# Centering multiply images

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I have a small problem i think it's rather simple though.

Basically i have a site looking like this.

[image]

On my screen it looks great now, but when i drag in the browser window and such it doesn't look to great.

I want the IMG1 and IMG2 to be in the center of the site, with IMG2 on top of IMG1.

```
#IMG1 {position: absolute; top: 5%; left: 25%;}

#IMG2 {position: absolute; top: 15%; left: 34.80%;}
```

and like div id="img1" etc.

Are there any tips to centering two images like this?
I am using fancybox for the images since i need a popup window if that has something to say.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Look at the HTML and CSS below. For aligning absolute position to the center of the screen you have to assign left and right as `0` and then `margin:0px auto` to give the result.

**HTML**

```
<div class="bgimg">
  <div class="img1"></div>
  <div class="img2"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .bgimg
{
 background:url(http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/32854-image/First-samples-from-Sonys-new-13MP-stacked-camera-sensor-capable-of-HDR-video-show-up.jpg);
position:relative;
width:500px;
height:500px;
margin:0px auto;
}
.img1
{
background:url(http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/article/47006-image/Alleged-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-photosphere-sample-unearthed.jpg) no-repeat;
width:200px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
top:20px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0px auto;
}
.img2
{
 background:url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/pub/image-pJdq08BYi8MHY3zGf5zIydXbyfSka31-0GzQKp6YyB0u7ONcpJdQHUaYyXkB7hcsRKBQ/melody-sample.jpg) no-repeat;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:0;
right:0;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SL5G2/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you need overlapping, the absolute positioning seems to be needed, a simple approach to accomplish that if you know the images dimensions is to positioning the images at 50% and "substract" the half of the width in the margin-left.
I provide a fiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/dR7z8/

```
<div id="bg">
    <img id="img2" src="http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/Watches/Google/Google_watch_concept-578-80.jpg"/>
    <img id="img1" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/sAnKrUFttffrMsAJUgM_H8la1sw5cKqbROwgZUU6MOqjlKUbsNGCfm4elZ2jAtfqA0c=w300" />
</div>
#bg{position: relative;}
#img2{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -289px;
}
#img1{
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
}
}
```

But I think that it could be more simple to use a img and a background div with the other image, something like this:

```
<div id="bg">
    <div id="img2"><img id="img1" src="https://lh3.ggpht.com/sAnKrUFttffrMsAJUgM_H8la1sw5cKqbROwgZUU6MOqjlKUbsNGCfm4elZ2jAtfqA0c=w300" /></div>

</div>
#img2
{
 background:url("http://cdn1.mos.techradar.futurecdn.net//art/Watches/Google/Google_watch_concept-578-80.jpg") no-repeat top;
    text-align: center;
padding-top: 5%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frikinside/88DZr/